# How can I write a button in an ng-repeat that affects the object the element is based on?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a bunch of recordings in an array. Each recording is an object with a lot of different components.

I have an `ng-repeat` that for each of those records, shows a box with the recording's name, length, and then a play and delete button.

I know how to write a click event for when the button is pressed, but how do I know which object in the array the button belonged to? The play and delete buttons need to act on that record and that record alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either pass the object to the ng-click function:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in records">
    <button ng-click="play(record)">Play</button>
</div>
```

or call a function on the record in the ng-click:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in records">
    <button ng-click="record.play()">Play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, smart. I think I'm gonna go with adding a function to the objects and calling it with ng-click. Thank you! Also, now I feel dumb for using click events instead of ng-click :/

Answer (score 0):

Just another way by index :

```
$scope.recordings = [];
$scope.play = function($index){
   $scope.playing = $index;
   $scope.item = $scope.recordings[$index];
}
...   
ng-repeat="rec in recordings" ng-click="play($index)"></div>
```